# How to dump a file stored in a sqlite database as a blob?

Tags: sqlite, blob

I have a sqlite3 database. One column has the TEXT type, and contains blobs which I would like to save as file. Those are gzipped files.

The output of the command `sqlite3 db.sqlite3 ".dump"`  is:

`INSERT INTO "data" VALUES(1,'objects','object0.gz',X'1F8B080000000000000 [.. a few thousands of hexadecimal characters ..] F3F5EF')`

How may I extract the binary data from the sqlite file to a file using the command line ?

Comment: What kind of command line?

Comment: I mean by running sqlite3 in a terminal.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`sqlite3` cannot output binary data directly, so you have to convert the data to a hexdump, use `cut` to extract the hex digits from the blob literal, and use `xxd` (part of the `vim` package) to convert the hexdump back into binary:

```sh
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT quote(MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1;"  \
| cut -d\' -f2                                                   \
| xxd -r -p                                                      \
> object0.gz
```

With SQLite 3.8.6 or later, the command-line shell includes the `fileio` extension, which implements the [`writefile` function](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#fileio):

```sh
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT writefile('object0.gz', MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1"
```

Comment: cut -d\' -f2 accomplishes the same task and is a little easier to type than the sed statement above.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `writefile` if using the `sqlite3` command line tool:

Example usage:
`select writefile('blob.bin', blob_column) from table where key='12345';`

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I use "hex" instead of "quote" to retrieve image from database, and no need "cut" in the command pipe. For example:

```
sqlite3 fr.db "select hex(bmp) from reg where id=1" | xxd -r -p > 2.png
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to make some minor changes on [CL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl)'s answer, in order to make it work for me:

- The structure for the command that he is using does not have the database name in it, the syntax that I am using is something like:

  ```
  sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite3 "Select quote(BlobField) From TableWithBlod Where StringKey = '1';" | ...
  ```
- The way he is using the `cut` command does not work in my machine. The correct way for me is:

  ```
  cut -d "'" -f2
  ```

So the final command would be something like:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite3 "Select quote(BlobField) From TableWithBlod Where StringKey = '1';" | cut -d "'" -f2 | xxd -r -p > myfile.extension
```

And in my case:

```
sqlite3 osm-carto_z14_m8_m.mbtiles "select quote(images.tile_data) from images where images.tile_id = '1';" | cut -d "'" -f2 | xxd -r -p > image.png
```

Comment: BTW, in my case `xxd` could deal with the hexdump both with quotes or without quotes