# How to execute writefile function in sqlite3 database using C++

Tags: c++, sqlite, dump

I'm trying to dump a file from sqlite3 database using C++ function.
I have tried this on terminal command and it works perfectly but here it's not executed.

errmsg=:
**no such function: writefile**

```
bool Database::download(string username, string filename){

    string query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM FILES WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"';";
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(dbFile,query.c_str(),private_callback,(void *)data,&errmsg);
    if(rc==SQLITE_OK){
        cout<<"this username dont have any uploaded files!"<<endl;
        return false;

    }
    else{
        query = "SELECT writefile('"+filename+"',FILE) FROM FILES WHERE USERNAME='"+username+"' AND FILENAME='"+filename+"';";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(dbFile,query.c_str(),private_callback,(void *)data,&errmsg);

        if(rc!=SQLITE_OK){
            cout<<errmsg<<endl;
            return false;
        }
        elsereturn true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, can't seem to do it via the app... but was able to do it via command line.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448373/how-to-dump-a-file-stored-in-a-sqlite-database-as-a-blob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions) says:

> Note that the readfile(X) and writefile(X,Y) functions are extension functions and are not built into the core SQLite library. These routines are available as a [loadable extension](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) in the [ext/misc/fileio.c](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/misc/fileio.c) source file in the  [SQLite source code repositories](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html#srctree).